# Does Apps for Website feature work on 3rd party browsers?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, browser, apps-for-website

A word about this feature:

Websites such as Facebook open their official apps when a user visits their website on a browser. This feature allows us to disable/enable such switching to apps. It allows us to choose whether we want to view content in browser or in an app.

---

Now back to the question. **Will this feature work with 3rd party browsers such as UC? Or is it meant just for Edge?**

---

Note: All the 3rd party browsers I use are not updated after AU. So I cannot test it myself. I am expecting some references that MS has allowed it or some personal experiences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is safe to assume that the Apps for Website feature does not and will not work with 3rd party browsers, as this has not worked so far.